# calling webservices from cloverETL

Tags: etl

Which version of cloverETL is needed to invoke webservices? I was looking at the site http://www.cloveretl.com/ and got confused with so many product variations.

how does it compare to oracle ODI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebServiceClient component ( http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/webserviceclient.html ) is available in commercial distribution of:

- CloverETL Designer
- CloverETL Server
- CloverETL Cluster

It of course available also in evaluation versions of products above. WebServiceClient is great and simple to use tool for accessing web services, allowing simple request generating and response handling.

In community edition version is available also component HTTPConnector ( http://doc.cloveretl.com/documentation/UserGuide/index.jsp?topic=/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/httpconnector.html ) which can be used for the same purpose. But you need to prepare request and process response by your own.